# How to pass output data between airflow SSHOperator tasks using xcom?

Tags: airflow

Problem summary:

- I need to get stdout from one SSHOperator using xcom
- Filter some rows and get output values for passing them to another SSHOperator

Unfortunatelly I've not find anything helpful in the Airflow documentation

Code example:

```
import airflow
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.contrib.operators.ssh_operator import SSHOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0),
}

dag = airflow.DAG(
    'example',
    default_args=default_args,
)

task_dummy = DummyOperator(
    task_id='task_dummy',
    dag=dag
)

cmd_ssh = """
for f in "file1" "file2"
do
    if $(hdfs dfs -test -d /data/$f)
        then hdfs dfs -rm -r -skipTrash /data/$f
        else echo "doesn't exists"
    fi
done
"""

task_1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='server_connection',
    task_id='task_ssh',
    command=cmd_ssh,
    do_xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

My question is - how to access stdout from task_1 when I sed do_xcom_push=True?

Answer (score -1):

You can access the [XCom](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) data in templated fields or callables which receive the Airflow context, such as the `PythonOperator` (*and its child classes*) -- from the documentation:

```py
# inside a PythonOperator called 'pushing_task'
def push_function():
    return value

# inside another PythonOperator where provide_context=True
def pull_function(**context):
    value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='pushing_task')
```

Comment: I guess that his question is related to SSHOperator, not PythonOpertaor.

Comment: Their question, as I read it is "My question is - how to access stdout from task_1 when I sed do_xcom_push=True?" -- to which I explained how XCom data is accessible in templated fields, and contexts, by way of the task instance, and showed an example.